# $RP^1$ is not a regular level surface of any $C^1$ map from $RP^2$ into $R$

Tags: differential-topology

Since $RP^2$ is compact and connected, its continuous image in $R$ is a closed interval.  Let $f$ be this map.  Suppose $RP^1 = f^{-1}(c)$.  If $c$ is in the interior of $[a,b]$ then $RP^2$ \ $RP^1$ is not connected.  Hence $c=a$ or $c=b$.  WLOG assume $c=a$.  I next want to argue that $f$ achieving a minimum on $RP^1$ implies $df = 0$ on $RP^1$, hence not surjective.As this problem arose in the context of a differential topology problem, I am hesitant to conclude that all partial derivatives of $f$ are zero at $p$, hence $df_p$ is null.  I feel that any reference to partial derivatives requires mention of a chart.  Therefore, how, in the language of differential topology, would I rigorously phrase such a conclusion?

Since first posting this question, I have some new thoughts.  As I said in a later comment, this is as the question appeared on a qualifying exam.  I think $f$ has to be smooth as opposed to merely $C^1$ since the Regular Level Set Theorem can only be applied with a smooth function.  If $f$ is smooth, then the tangent plane of $R$ at $c$ can be spanned by $\frac{\partial f}{ \partial x_i} \Big|_p$ and if $c$ is the minimal value $f$ achieves in $R$, then given any $v \in T_p RP^2$, curve $\gamma: [0,1] \mapsto RP^2$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$, and $\gamma'(0) = v$, then $\sum_i v_i \frac{\partial f}{ \partial x_i} \Big|_p = df_p(v) = (f \circ \gamma)'(0) = 0$, hence $\frac{\partial f}{ \partial x_i} \Big|_p = 0$ for every $i$?

Comment: I edited your post to $\LaTeX$ify it.  Remember your "\$" signs!  Also, are you sure you mean $c \in \Bbb R$, and not in the domain of $f$?

Comment: Suppose $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb R$ maps $x\mapsto |x|$. It is continuous. It takes its minimum value at $0$, but $df_0$ does not exist.

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Hint: express $df_p$ in coordinates.

Comment: The connected, compact manifold in question is actually $RP^2$, so WLOG  assume $p$ is in $U_3 := \{ [x_1, x_2 , x_3] : x_3 \neq 0\}$ , which, with $\phi_3 ([x_1, x_2, x_3])= (x_1 / x_3, x_2/x_3 )$, $\phi_3^{-1} = [x_1, x_2, 1]$, defines a chart on $RP^2$.  The image of f in $R$ is some $[c,d]$ and take as a chart any open set in $R$ containing $[c,d]$ and the identity map on $R$.  So in coordinates, $df_p = [ df/dx_1 df/dx_2]$?  I am not comfortable with such translation, hence the post.

Comment: Furthermore, what conclusions does $f(p) = c$ allow me to make?  I am hoping to get the conclusion is $df_p$ is zero map.

Comment: The Regular Level Set Theorem (if it is what I think you are referring to) applies to $C^1$ maps; in general fibers will be as good as the map.

Answer (score 0):

Let your connected compact space be $S^1=\{(x,y)\,|\,x^2+y^2=1\}\subset{\mathbb R}^2$. The function $f(x,y):=x$ assumes its minimum on $S^1$ at the point $p:=(-1,0)$, but $\nabla f(x,y)\equiv(1,0)$ is $\ne{\bf 0}$ at $p$.

Your idea of a "compact connected space" has to be made more precise.

Comment: I did not include the actual question I was trying to solve as I thought I had isolated the remaining issue.    Here it is exactly as it appeared on a qualifying exam at my university:  "Regarding $S^1$ as the equator of $S^2$, we obtain $RP^1$ as a submanifold of $RP^2$.  Show that $RP^1$ is not a regular level surface of any $C^1$ map from $RP^2$ into $R$."

Answer (score 0):

If a submanifold $N\subset M$ is the preimage of a regular value for some smooth mapping $U\to\Bbb R^k$ ($N\subset U\subset M$, $U$ open), then the normal bundle of $N$ is $M$ must be trivial. But you can easily check that the normal bundle of $\Bbb RP^1$ in $\Bbb RP^2$ is not a trivial line bundle. (You can check this either analytically or topologically.)

Let me emphasize you should not be asking about a function defined on all of $\Bbb RP^2$ to start with. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments!  As I said in the comments to Christian Blatter's comments, the original question, as given on a past qualifying exam, is about a $C^1$ function defined on $RP^2$.  Also, the differential topology part of the sequence was taught with Lee's $Introduction$ $to$ $Smooth$ $Manifolds$ as the textbook, but we didn't study the normal line bundle.  Is there some way to approach the problem without this viewpoint?

Comment: Do you understand how $\Bbb RP^1$ sits inside $\Bbb RP^2$ topologically? And what would the function have to look like around $\Bbb RP^1$ if the $\Bbb RP^1$ is the preimage of $0$ and $0$ is a regular value?

Comment: Viewing $RP^2$ as $D^2/( x$ ~ $-x)$, $RP^1$ would be the boundary.  This is why I thought that under any continuous map on $RP^2$ into the reals, the image of $RP^1$ would have to be one of the endpoints of a closed interval.  Since the differential is surjective at every point in a regular value and the target space is $R$, then the image of the differential would have to be one dimensional.  I am trying to get the conclusion that this is not the case by showing it is zero but I do not how to do this rigorously via the language of differential topology.

Comment: Well, you're right. But what's your proof? And why does this contradict regular value?